# Magento module not calling install script, to create attribute for category

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating module in magento 1.9.1, to create a attribute for categories. I have created files as follows:

> app\etc\modules\Ddevs_Ebayaff.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <Ddevs_Ebayaff>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Ddevs_Ebayaff>
     </modules>
</config>
```

I am trying to call controller and mysql install script in one config file as follows

> app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\etc\config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> <config>
        <modules>
            <ddevs_ebayaff>
                <version>
                    0.1.0
                </version>
            </ddevs_ebayaff>
        </modules>   
          <frontend>
            <routers>
                <helloworld>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff</module>
                        <frontName>ebayaffload</frontName>
                    </args>
                </helloworld>
            </routers>
        </frontend>     
     <global>
     <resources>
        <add_category_attribute>
            <setup>
                <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </add_category_attribute>
    </resources>

</global>
     </config>
```

In IndexController, i have the following content

> app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Ddevs_Ebayaff_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
           $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

And my install script as follows:

> app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\sql\add_category_attribute\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'ddev_ebayaff_cat', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Category ID',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing this in the `config.xml` inside the `<global>` tag

```
    <resources>
        <add_category_attribute>
            <setup>
                <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </add_category_attribute>
    </resources>
```

also change this section from the same config file

```
<ddevs_ebayaff>
    <version>
        0.1.0
    </version>
</ddevs_ebayaff>
```

to

```
<Ddevs_Ebayaff>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</Ddevs_Ebayaff>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I changed the xml file according to your suggestion, but still no luck in creating category attribute.

Comment: The code looks right in rest. Maybe the problem is different. Try to debug using this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146. and this to see how it's done: http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

Comment: I tried to debug, but no errors are showing up and the module is not going through the mysql4-install-0.1.0.php. Even if i add die statement into it, nothing is happening.

Comment: maybe your module was already installed. check the table `core_resource` for a line with code `add_category_attribute`. If there is one, delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!, I uninstalled the extension completely and installed again and the attribute is created correctly. Thanks once again..

Answer (score 3):

For your specific problem, you are missing the `<resources>` configuration in your module config. You need to add it directly under the `<global>` tag

```
<resources>
    <add_category_attribute>
        <setup>
            <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff</module>
            <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </add_category_attribute>
</resources>
```

<sup>The `<add_category_attribute>` tag should be the same as the directory name which contains your install scripts.</sup>

Other than that, you have different issues in your `config.xml`.

You cannot put a `<frontend>` tag inside `<global>`. The thing is, most of your module configuration fall under ONE of three tags.

- `<frontend>`
  Configuration under this tag, applies only to the frontend of Magento.
  These can be for example new routes just for the frontend.
- `<admin>`
  Configuration under this tag, applies only to the backend of Magento.
  These can be for example new routes just for the backend
- `<global>`
  Configuration under this tag, applies everywhere in Magento.
  These can be for example configuration for models, block, helpers.

This is how your `config.xml` should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ddevs_Ebayaff>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ddevs_Ebayaff>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </add_category_attribute>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff</module>
                    <frontName>ebayaffload</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi, I replaced the config file with the above, but category attribute is not creating yet.

Comment: @dynamicdevs Do you get an error when you open Magento or does it open normally? Can you post the output of the following MySQL query `select version, data_version from core_resource where code='add_category_attribute';`?

Comment: Thanks for your help!!, I uninstalled the extension completely and installed again and the attribute is created correctly. Thanks once again..